# Use JWT Token with SignalR

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, jwt, asp.net-core-signalr

I want to receive signalR requests with the JWT token. But an error occurs when React app tries to start the connection. I get an error like this
**ERROR: Cross-Origin Request Blocked: The Same Origin Policy disallows reading the remote resource at https://localhost:5001/hub/users/negotiate?negotiateVersion=1. (Reason: CORS request did not succeed). Status code: (null).2**

What is the mistake?

React code

```
export const connect = (url: string) => {
  const { token } = importFromLocalStorage('user');
  const connect = new HubConnectionBuilder()
    .withUrl(url, { accessTokenFactory: () => `Bearer ${token}` })
    .withAutomaticReconnect()
    .build();
  return connect;
};
```

.NET configuration code

```
builder.Services.AddCors(options => options.AddDefaultPolicy(builder =>
{
    builder.WithOrigins("http://localhost:3000")
        .AllowAnyHeader()
        .AllowAnyMethod()
        .AllowCredentials();
}));

builder.Services.AddAuthentication(options =>
    {
        options.DefaultAuthenticateScheme = JwtBearerDefaults.AuthenticationScheme;
        options.DefaultChallengeScheme = JwtBearerDefaults.AuthenticationScheme;
    })
    .AddJwtBearer(options =>
    {
        options.TokenValidationParameters = new TokenValidationParameters()
        {
            ValidateIssuer = true,
            ValidateAudience = true,
            ValidateLifetime = true,
            ValidateIssuerSigningKey = true,
            RequireExpirationTime = true,
            ValidIssuer = builder.Configuration["Jwt:Issuer"],
            ValidAudience = builder.Configuration["Jwt:Audience"],
            ClockSkew = TimeSpan.Zero,
            IssuerSigningKey = new SymmetricSecurityKey(Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(builder.Configuration[signinKey]))
        };
        
        options.Events = new JwtBearerEvents()
        {
            OnMessageReceived = context =>
            {
                var accessToken = context.Request.Query["access_token"];

                var path = context.HttpContext.Request.Path;
                if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(accessToken) &&
                    (path.StartsWithSegments("/hub")))
                {
                    context.Token = accessToken;
                }
                return Task.CompletedTask;
            }
        };
    });
```

.NET Hub code

```
[Authorize(AuthenticationSchemes = JwtBearerDefaults.AuthenticationScheme)]
public class UsersHub : Hub
{
    public override Task OnConnectedAsync()
    {
        var x = this.Context.ConnectionId;
        return base.OnConnectedAsync();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You've allowed only origins that come from domain `http://localhost:3000`.

Make sure that you allow also `https://localhost:5001`.

```
builder.Services.AddCors(options => options.AddDefaultPolicy(builder =>
{
    builder.WithOrigins("http://localhost:3000", "https://localhost:5001")
        .AllowAnyHeader()
        .AllowAnyMethod()
        .AllowCredentials();
}));
```

I believe that you have `app.UseCors();` inside your **Configuration** method.

Comment: Still not working :(  I have app.UseCors(); below